# Adding JTable Model (IntelliJ Forms)

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I am trying to add a model to a JTable, which was created using IntelliJ Forms. As of right now, the main method has to be static, and if I make the JTable static as well, then IntelliJ says it cannot bind the JTable. I am confused on how I can add the model in this case.

```
public class DisplaySettings {
    private JTable resolutionsTable;
    private JPanel displaySettings;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display Settings");
        frame.setContentPane(new DisplaySettings().displaySettings);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        String[] columns = {"Resolution Size"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0);

        resolutionsTable.setModel(model);
    }

}
```

Comment: just to reproduce, what is `Xrandr` here?

Comment: @nullpointer sorry. Irrelevant. It works. I stepped through it and adds everything it should. The problem line is resolutionsTable.setModel(model);. This is because the main method has to be static and the JTable can't be static so I'm confused how to set the model, when using IntelliJ Forms, actually make the JTable hold data

Comment: Now that it's been modified, if I try to run this code I would get an `IllegalComponentStateException` from the line `frame.setContentPane(new DisplaySettings().displaySettings);`

Comment: and did you try instantiating it `JTable resolutionsTable = new JTable();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are dealing with IntelliJ Forms, they are automatically handled and allocated for by IntelliJ, by default. If you select the component you are working with in the `ComponentTree`, in the `.form` GUI Editor, there is an option called `Custom Create`. Check that.

[image]

Once that is checked, IntelliJ will automatically create a method called `createUIComponents()`. There you can allocate your `JTable` and set the model, since this method is not in a static context. This method will be automatically called when creating the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following works for me -

```
JTable resolutionsTable = new JTable(); // instances of both JTable and JPanel
JPanel displaySettings = new JPanel();
... // you can set the above component with diff attributes
frame.setContentPane(displaySettings);
... // and use them further
resolutionsTable.setModel(model);
```

Comment: Did you use an IntelliJ Form to do this?